# Exchange Web Services 404 error

Tags: exchangewebservices

I'm attempting to connect to Office 365's Exchange Web Services, but it keeps coming up with a 404 error. I'm pretty sure the issue is with the credentials, but I seem to lack the knowledge to resolve it.

I performed a test via testconnectivity.microsoft.com (Service Account Access test under the Office 365 tab) and it is also getting a 404 error. I know from searching online that the format of the credentials is a common problem, however it is in the 'user@company.com' format.

I think the problem may have something to do with the domain or that the authentication goes through my company's server. For example, if I log into outlook.office365.com with the 'user@company.com' format, it forwards me to my company's log on portal (I believe this is a typical setup). In order to log in, I first have to change the user name from the 'user@company.com' format to 'user@domain' or 'domain\user' (the domain is different from the company name).

My question is, since the authentication goes through my company's server, do I need to authenticate to Exchange Web Services in a different manner? (Currently I'm using a WebCredential)

Alternatively, if my company's portal were to accept user@company.com as a valid user name, would that allow me to connect to EWS using a WebCredential?

This is the code I'm using for the connection, however I don't think it is the problem given that Microsoft's test site was also getting a 404 error.

```
service = new ExchangeService();
service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("user@company.com", "password");
service.Url = "https://outlook.office365.com/ews/exchange.asmx";
```

Comment: Where is the Mailbox located that the credentials your using belong to ? eg if your Exchange is Hybrid this means you may have mailboxes OnPremise and Mailboxes in the Cloud. It sounds like from what your describing is the mailbox your trying to use in OnPremise and they haven't exposed the EWS Endpoint OnPremise which would give you 404. If you use something like fiddler you should be able to see what's happening to your request and if they are being redirected etc

Comment: Not sure where my mailbox is at, though I'll try to find out. I downloaded Fiddler and checked the traffic. The first response is an HTTP 401 Unauthorized, which is when I get prompted to enter credentials. The second response is an HTTP 404, it doesn't appear to be a redirect. However, under Miscellaneous there is an `X-CasErrorCode: UserNotFound` which I'm guessing means there's something wrong with how the accounts are set up currently.

Comment: Its means the user isn't in the cloud so you need to use the EWS endpoint for you onprem server.

Comment: Curious, I ran the "Test E-mail AutoConfiguration" on Outlook and it came up with `outlook.office365.com/ews/exchange.asmx` for the availability service. Prior to completing the test, it did connect to my company's portal and prompt for credentials however.

Comment: You need to talk to your admin they should be able to tell you definitively where the Mailbox is located.